# Need old version Firefox Java plugin

Tags: java, firefox-3.6

I need to use Java 1.6.0_20 for the software I'm running.  I went to the Oracle website and downloaded jre1.6.0_20 and installed it on my computer, but can't seem to get Firefox to load Java.  If I download directly from http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp, the plugin works fine but is the wrong version, and I can't find on www.java.com anywhere to download any of the previous versions. According to the help (can't post link because of spam prevention), I need to go into the Java Control Panel and enable it for Mozilla.  I've done this multiple times, but every time I go in to the control panel and check the box, click Apply and Save, as soon as I go back in the box is unchecked.

Does anyone know either why the box is unchecked, or where I can download the old JRE that also is configured for Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

All the Firefox Plugins are called "Java Console 6.0.XX" for Java 6, so I just did a search for "java console 6.0.20 download" and found a link that installed Java and the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on Vista/Windows 7 with UAC enabled? You need to run as administrator to save the changes. You can log in as administrator and make the changes if you have configured your machine to allow that. Alternative:

- Find "Console Prompt" in the start menu.
- Right click.
- Select "Run as administrator".
- Click "Continue" on the UAC "security" pop-up.
- Run "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javacpl.exe".
- Configure and save as usual.

(There are probably better ways of doing this.)